# Error in uploading Multiple Images in ReactNative

Tags: react-native, multipartform-data, multer, form-data

```
const availabilityData = new FormData();

  availabilityData.append('name', title);
  availabilityData.append('foodType', foodType);
  availabilityData.append('availability_type', category);
  availabilityData.append('description', description);
  availabilityData.append('total_quantity', quantity);
  availabilityData.append('cooked_time', madeOn);
  availabilityData.append('best_before', bestBefore);
  availabilityData.append('storage_description', storageDesc);
  availabilityData.append('latitude', fromLocation.latitude);
  availabilityData.append('longitude', fromLocation.longitude);
  availabilityData.append('city', selectedCity);
  availabilityData.append('creator_delivery_option', deliveryOption);

  for (let i = 0; i < imageLoc.length; i++) {
    const newFile = {
      uri: imageLoc[i],
      type: 'image/jpg',
      name: new Date(),
    };
    availabilityData.append('files[]', newFile);
  }

  await axios({
    url: constants.BASE_URL + 'availability/createAvailability',
    method: 'post',
    data: availabilityData,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `UserData ${token}`,
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },

  })
    .then(function (response) {
      Alert.alert('Availability Created Successfully');
      navigation.popToTop();
      removeAllInputs();
      setLoading(false);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
      setLoading(false);
    });
}
```

imageLoc is the State where I have stored the location of selected Images.

output when I print imageLoc:
["content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADCIM%2FCamera%2FWe4Us%2FWe4Us-151358739.jpg", "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADCIM%2FCamera%2FWe4Us%2FWe4Us-151913720.jpg", "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADCIM%2FCamera%2FWe4Us%2FWe4Us-15253326.jpg", "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADCIM%2FCamera%2FWe4Us%2FWe4Us-152139570.jpg", "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADCIM%2FCamera%2FWe4Us%2FWe4Us-1524187.jpg"]

[Error I got in the backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5x8R.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are having Content-Provider paths in your file array. A content provider is not a valid url in Android and probably Axios is not prepared to handle them. In this case you can copy the files for example with react-native-fs to a different location:

```
RNFS.copyFile(uri, targetPath)
```

And then provide the targetPath to axios. Make sure to delete the copies after sending the images.

Comment: now imageLoc is like this : 

file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/We4Us/We4Us-194247905.jpg", "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/We4Us/We4Us-19425494.jpg", "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/We4Us/We4Us-194259423.jpg", "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/We4Us/We4Us-19435187.jpg", "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/We4Us/We4Us-194311184.jpg

but still having the same error

Comment: I am not sure, maybe the wrong extension of the filename (you do not have any) is creating the problem, try to track down the issue to one file and simplify your request